# "closeOnSelect" in "AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect" leads the popup close

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I write

```
selectionLimit: 1,
closeOnSelect:true,
closeOnDeselect:true,
```

in property of AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect. 
And I use this dropdown on popup window.
When I select one element on the dropdown, the popup closes. 
I want to close only the dropdown and want to keep the popup open.
Only solution I have is to set as below

```
closeOnSelect:false,
closeOnDeselect:false,
```

However I want to close the dropdown when I select elements.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think its issue from your code. it will not close the modal popup. it will only close the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you. I will fix my code.